# Prevenir que a Borda do Elemento cresça ao usar Transform:Scale

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

É uma pergunta bem simples, mas não encontrei resposta...

Eu tenho um elemento que tem uma `borda` de `1px`. Porém quando eu faço um `:hover` nele eu aplico um `transform:scale()` mas a largura da `borda` dele tb parece aumentar, até tentei colocar `0.01px`, mas não deu certo.

Tem alguma forma de corrigir isso sem ter que criar um *pseudo-elemento*?

```css
body {
    margin: 2rem;
}
.box {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-right: 1rem;
transition: transform 500ms;
}
.box:hover {
    transform: scale(2) translate(25%, 25%);
border: 0.1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Se o elemento possuir um texto, ele deve ser afetado pelo `scale`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss não necessariamente, o que está me incomodando mesmo a a borda crescendo junto com o elemento, pois o conteúdo interno da div eu já imaginava que cresceria junto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isto acontece porque o  `transform: scale(2)` escala todo o objeto, inclusive sua borda. Para que não aconteça, tavez seja mais interessante aumentar seu `height` e `width`, mas seu conteúdo não vai acompanha-lo. Se for mesmo necessário usar scale, experimente trocar o border por um box shadow pois não existe pixel "quebrado" mas estranhamente com box shadow funciona, como no exemplo:

```css
body {
    margin: 2rem;
}
.box {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #000;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    transition: box-shadow 500ms, transform 500ms;
}
.box:hover {
    transform: scale(2) translate(25%, 25%);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px .55px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: É uma opção valeu a dica!

Comment: Espero ter ajudado. Disponha.

Comment: só acho interessante substituir os meio pixels por outra unidade `em`, teoricamente pixels só podem e devem ser representados por inteiros.